Is $V$ in electric power potential difference or is it absolute potential?
Recently I had a thought that when we step up or step down the voltage in a transformer, assuming no energy dissipation, we are just conserving the energy. Assuming that the material of primary and secondary coil to be same, the resistivity of the coils should be same. So, for a given potential difference, say, the amount of current flowing through the coils, and consequently, the wires (or circuit) they are part of is same.
Now, if that is true, then for a potential difference $V1$, current is $I1$ (say). Now, we stepped the voltage up, that means there is more potential difference $V2$, so, the corresponding current should be greater. But, we know, that following energy conservation, the current will be lesser than the initial current.
But isn't it contradictory to the fact that for a fixed resistance (or resistivity for a fixed length) the current that will flow will be directed proportional to the potential difference? This led me to the question that whether the $V$ in $P=VI$ represents potential difference or absolute potential. Also, if it means potential difference, then why the energy conservation leads us to the conclusion that current will be lower for a higher voltage? I want an answer which gives me a feel of the concept. Also, I want to be pointed out, where I have gone wrong in my reasoning. Microscopic level explanation is also welcomed.

Hi Hrishikesh. Welcome to Phys.SE. What is your definition of absolute potential?

Like, if we consider the potential at infinity to be 0, then the potential at a point.

A voltmeter always measures a potential difference. Also the current in the primary coil is affected by the current in the secondary coil; if the latter is increased (by changing the load resistance), then so is the former.

Or I shall frame my question as is it potential difference or something related to potential/voltage but somehow different.

Yes, sir (Peter), but I am confused about why exactly energy conservation leads us to the conclusion that the current had to be less for a higher voltage, even if the material is same. Mutual induction leads to the formation of current in the secondary coil, but the voltage is high, yet the current is low compared to the initial low voltage current. So, shall we rethink of resistance? Please answer.


So, for a given potential difference, say, the amount of current
flowing through the coils, and consequently, the wires (or circuit)
they are part of is same.

No, that is not the case.
For an ideal transformer the ohmic resistance of the primary and secondary coils is considered to be zero. That means the current in the coils is dictated by the inductive reactance of each coil applicable to the frequency of the voltage source applied to the primary. All other things being equal, the greater the number of turns, the greater that reactance.
Since there are more primary turns than secondary turns for a step down transformer, the reactance is greater in the primary than secondary. That means the current is less in the primary than the secondary. Finally, since power is conserved the product of the voltage and current is the same in the primary and secondary. Thus the secondary voltage is less than the primary.
Hope this helps.

I was also expecting such an answer. Thanks. So, the thing that the current is less in the second coil of a step up transformer is attributed to the more inductive reactance of it. And the thing that the resistance (ideally zero, but practically non zero) same for both side (as I considered) follows the ohm'd law without violation. So, if we think , that hypothetically (violating the energy conservation, I am just thinking and not violating, just thinking a case) if the coils had no reactance and only resistance, then it should have increased the current in step up transformer. Thanks again.

If there was no reactance it would mean there’s no inductance. There would be no transformer

But can you please show it explicitly using mathematics? That how only reactance is responsible for the reduced current. If I go through the equation, P=VI × power factor, then I m not getting any satisfactory result.

Don't forget reactance only applies to inductors and capacitors. Without reactance there  is no inductance. Without inductance there is no  alternating magnetic field generated in the primary coil to be coupled to the secondary coil producing a voltage in the secondary.

So, we have to use V=IZ for this case. P=VI cos phi is just about power dissipation. Since, Z=XL, so V=IXL. Okay.

@Hrishikesh  $Z_{L}=jX_{L}$ where $X_L$ is the inductive reactance (magnitude of the impedance). For a sinusoidal voltage  $X_{L}=\omega L=2\pi fL$. For ideal inductor (no ohmic resistance) the current and voltage are 90 deg out of phase so $\cos\phi =0$ and there is no power dissipation. For the inductor the product of the voltage and current is call reactive power.

The big problem you are running into is that you seem to think that the current in the primary is given by the voltage across the primary and the resistivity of the material of the primary. This is not the case. The current through the primary is driven by the inductive coupling with the secondary, not by the resistivity of the primary.
This page seems like a good overview, starting from the “On Load” section. Note that the current in the primary is limited even if the primary resistance is considered to be 0. You must account for the inductance.

why it turns out that a high voltage is accompanied by low current

In an ideal transformer the magnetic flux through the primary is the same as the magnetic flux through the secondary. The more turns a coil has, the smaller the current that is required to make a given magnetic field, and the bigger the voltage that is produced as the flux changes. So if you double the turns (keeping the flux and change in flux the same) then you will halve the current and double the voltage.

Like, I have the confusion about how can high voltage accompany a low current and not the sources of current. Yes I somewhat know about inductance (here Mutual inductance, also the primary coil has its self inductance). But, the thing is why it turns out that a high voltage is accompanied by low current. Is it like the impedance is higher on the secondary coil side? So that the effective current is less than the primary side? Please help on this matter.

Hmm, thanks for the article. Also, thnks for pointing out inductance. So, on a broad sense it is the impedance that reduces the current. Here, reduction is due to inductive reactance.

See the edits to the answer. This is not Ohm's law, you have to modify your thinking. Voltage and current are not proportional to each other except in resistors.

yes i got it. this is what i was looking for.
